# Under what conditions will the following circuit work?

Tags: power-supply, power, capacitor, rectifier

The following circuit that only has a single supply wire and not grounded (see below).  Under what condition can this circuit be made to work (supply a small amount of rectified current, say 5mA).

In theory, this should be possible (e.g. current flow in antennae).  Not sure how it can be done in a real experiment when there is no real ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNjLRF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: it will work if you cut the wire from D2 to D1 and hook D2 to ground

Comment: All I can think of require fairy dust

Comment: Maybe increase the 12VAC to 12kVAC...

Comment: I can actually see why you *think* it might work, but capacitors don't work that way. You can't selectively make the top of the capacitor positive and the bottom of it negative on opposing cycles - charging a cap requires current flow and that takes a complete circuit, even if it gets achieved in weird ways. For instance, you might actually see it work on a poorly constructed breadboard due to stray capacitance.

Answer (score 3):

It can't.

A schematic diagram is an *idealized* representation of a circuit, in the sense that the circuit nodes (places where components connect to each other) are assumed to not interact with other nodes *at all*.

Obviously, this cannot be true of any real physical circuit, but it's a convention that makes circuit analysis tractable.

If the "conditions" that you're referring to are some sort of leakage path or capacitive coupling that isn't shown in the diagram, you need to make that explicit.

For example, if certain nodes of your circuit had sufficient capacitive coupling to ground, a high-voltage transformer could conceivably drive enough current through it to light the LED.

Answer (score 2):

It won't work i.e. it won't drive the LED because you are unable to extract energy from the transformer secondary due to having only one connection to it. At 60Hz, you won't get any meaningful antenna type coupling of energy.

Comment: So even a 1/4 wave length antenna for 60Hz whis is 82445KM long wouldn't work?

Comment: Where would you connect this unfeasible antenna?

Comment: well if had that answer, I wouldn't be torturing you folks by posting this Q.  Maybe D1 to D2 Loop would be need to be 1/4 EL of 60Hz? like a 60Hz version of this: http://donheroziril.blogspot.ca/2012/05/free-energy-cellphone-detector-from.html

Comment: Any electromagnetic antenna solution that works would work without the single wire that joins the diodes to the transformer. Keeping the single connection clouds the issue I think you are trying to investigate. But, on the other hand, a large wire could capacitive couple to the transformer secondary and steal some energy but, you might as well have loosely coupled coils stealing energy then you are back to zero interconnections. Do you are my point?

Comment: Yes, I see your point.  Which takes me back to the beginning that it seems _possible_ but unclear how.

Comment: The most effective way to make it work is without the single wire by using induction from a transmit coil to a receive coil (that is replacing D2). It still works the same with the single wire connected of course.

Comment: If that scheme doesn't modify the grounded wire in the secondary (and does not ground itself), then that might very well be the answer.